# Matrix Element computation using outer in R

Tags: r, apply, dplyr

I am trying to compute each element of a matrix by a user defined function. I have used double `for` loops, nested `sapply`, and `apply` after `expand.grid`.

```
# create dataset
ll = lapply(1:20, FUN = function(x) floor(runif(n=floor(runif(1,10,30)),1,50)))

# sapply line
doSapply = function(ll){
  m = sapply(1:length(ll),FUN = function(x){sapply(1:length(ll),FUN = function(y){if(length(intersect(ll[[x]],ll[[y]]))>1){return(1)}else{return(0)}})})

}


doFor = function(ll){
  m = matrix(rep(0,length(ll)*length(ll)),length(ll))
  # double for loop
  for(x in 1:length(ll)){
    for(y in 1:length(ll)){
      if(length(intersect(ll[[x]],ll[[y]]))>1){
        m[x,y] = 1
      } else{
        m[x,y] = 0
      } 
    }
  }
}

doApply = function(ll){
  x = expand.grid(1:length(ll),1:length(ll))
  vals = apply(x,1,FUN = function(x){
    if(length(intersect(ll[[x[1]]],ll[[x[2]]]))>1){
      return(1)
    } else{
      return(0)
    }
  } )
  matrix(vals,nrow=length(ll),byrow=FALSE)
#   return(matrix(vals,nrow=length(ll),byrow=FALSE))
}
timeSapply = system.time(doSapply(ll))
timeFor = system.time(doFor(ll))
timeApply = system.time(doApply(ll))
```

I am looking for a more elegant solution (and faster, of course). I am trying to use outer, and I wrote:

```
doOuter = function(ll){
  outer(1:length(ll),1:length(ll),FUN = function(x,y){if(length(intersect(ll[[x]],ll[[y]]))>1){return(1)}else{return(0)}})
}
```

I got `Error in ll[[y]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2`

I figured Outer needs the function to be vectorized, so I tried it:

```
doMatch = function(x,y,ll){
  if(length(intersect(ll[[x]],ll[[y]]))>1){return(1)}else{return(0)}
}

doMatVec = Vectorize(doMatch)
outer(1:length(ll),1:length(ll),doMatVec,ll )
```

and I got `Error in ll[[x]] : subscript out of bounds`

I figure I might be going wrong in Vectorize, of the general idea of what I'm trying to do, but I'd appreciate some help here.
I'm also looking at `plyr`/`dplyr`- without much success.

Comment: Try `Vectorize(FUN, vectorize.args = c("x", "y"))`. You don't want the function vectorized in `ll`. However, `outer` is only fast if you pass it a function that is actually vectorized and not made so by a hidden `mapply` loop. You should consider carefully if you can rewrite `doMatch`. If you can't you should consider using `combn` to calculate only for the unique combinations of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Interesting question but above my pay grade. However I did take the time to time you functions > timeSapply
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.01 
> timeFor
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
> timeApply
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.02

Comment: Be interested to see if you can beat the for loop for this particular function.

Comment: @Roland, it worked. However, as you said, it is not faster than the previous methods. The results look like:
> timeSapply
   user  system elapsed 
105.758   0.000 103.158 
> timeFor
   user  system elapsed 
106.331   0.000 103.892 
> timeApply
   user  system elapsed 
173.619   0.000 169.920 
> timeOuter
   user  system elapsed 
114.963   0.000 112.707

Comment: Also, I'm calculating an adjecency matrix, need the full matrix for it. I'll try combn and see if something can come out of it though.